# pandas series loc by timestamp got "Level Type Mismatch". error

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am using a pandas.core.series.Series class, if I use iloc[0:1], I got proper result.

But if I use pandas.tslib.Timestamp, I am seeing "Level Type Mismatch".

Any suggestion to dive deep?

Comment: Can you add data sample?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure, but maybe you get [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3843) problem...  Idea - upgrade pandas should help also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, my time series has multiple index, like this:

```
field1  field2      day_field 
value1  value2     2010-01-01    True
                   2010-01-02    True
                   2010-01-03    True
                   2010-01-04    True
                   2010-01-05    True
dtype: bool
```

So if I use timestamp to slice, there is no way for pandas to figure out which index to slice.

It is actually very similar to https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3843